# How to check DataContractJsonSerializer DateTime has offset value present

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, datacontractjsonserializer

I have a date time receiving from DataContractJsonSerializer(webservice input).Normally the date time input will be actual local time of web service consumer, for example "2016-04-04T07:00:00.000000" but some web service consumers will pass datetime with an offset for example "2016-04-04T07:00:00.000000+01:00" then the WCF serializer on our end automatically converts XXXXX(Dublin time zone) time to YYYYY(Arizona) time, before we even get access to the variable.

Is there any way in c# to know the date time input has this +01:00 offset passed or it coming with actual local time without any offset.

Comment: Have you considered receiving it just as a string? I'd suggest using `DateTimeOffset`, but that doesn't have the notion of "no offset" separate from "offset of zero".

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am receiving it using DateTime object

Comment: Yes, I know - but that doesn't have this capability, and nor does `DateTimeOffset`, so I'm saying you may want to receive a string and parse it instead.